# Weird Batch File Issue

Tags: windows, windows-7, batch-file, windows-7-x64

Can someone help me with this one?   I have a batch file, where I am trying to connect a couple network drives based on my current internal IP address.  Problem is, it is outputting the following:

Home 192.168.2.99
Basement

Where it should be just outputting:
Home 192.168.2.99

Here's the code:

```
@echo off

@for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('"ipconfig | findstr IP | findstr 192."') do SET LOCAL_IP=%%i

@if ("%LOCAL_IP%" == "192.168.2.99") Call ConnectHome else (Call ConnectBasement)


:ConnectHome
@echo Home %LOCAL_IP%

:ConnectBasement
@echo Basement
@REM net use R: \\192.168.2.98\Storage
@REM net use S: \\192.168.2.98\MyStuff
@REM net use T: \\192.168.2.98\Server
```

I've also tried replacing the IF statement with:

```
@if ("%LOCAL_IP%" == "192.168.2.99") goto ConnectHome else (goto ConnectBasement)
```

and:

```
@if ("%LOCAL_IP%" == "192.168.2.99") goto :ConnectHome else (goto :ConnectBasement)
```

and the results are always the same...
OS is Windows 7 Pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Call` is intended to call a *different* batch file from the one you're currently in (see [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true)).  If it's passed a label, it will execute from that label, but it'll execute to the end of the file, so it won't stop when it hits the :ConnectBasement line.

What you probably need is to add a label `:END` at the bottom of the file, and `Goto :END` just before your :ConnectBasement line.  For consistency I'd probably suggest using `Goto` instead of `Call` throughout.  (You can also use `Goto :EOF` without defining a label, if you wish.)

(Or, learn PowerShell and use its functioning capability to implement this more cleanly ;-))

Answer (score 1):

After going to :ConnectHome, it just goes to :ConnectBasement. Add `goto :eof` just below `@echo Home %LOCAL_IP%`.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you forgetting to stop execution after the :ConnectHome part ?  I'm not sure, but I think the batch simply continues after that, printing "Basement".

edit: Jeroen beat me to it :)